# Бесконечный вывод <class 'set'> в консоль

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

После запуска обучения модели в консоль выводится <class 'set'> достаточно долгое время, после чего скрипт закрывается ни запустив обучение, ни сохранив логов

```
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential([
tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(5,), name='input_layer'),
tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', name='hidden_layer_1'),
tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(256, name='hidden_layer_2'),
tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(3, name='output_layer'),])

model.compile(
   optimizer='Adam',
   loss='mae',
   metrics=['mean_absolute_error']
   )
   model_checkpoint = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
      filepath='my_model', # путь к папке, где будет сохранена модель
      monitor='val_loss',
      save_best_only=True,
      mode='min'
   )

   model.fit(
      datas,
      resultst,
      validation_split=-.1,
      epochs=10,
      batch_size = 1000,
      callbacks= [
      model_checkpoint
      ]
    )
```

[image: Вывод консоли]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я использовал для передачи x_train и y_train обычные списки и еще пробовал массивы, но при старте тренировки я использовал свойство validation_split, которое можно использовать только при передачи x_train и y_train через numpy Array